# Jquery ID selector when attribute name has a hash

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm running into a problem, our internal framework has a system where if you have a form & the containing element his name starts with a hash-tag it will do something when processing these elements later on.

So I have for instance :

```
<label width='auto' for='x_test' >Test:</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="#x_test#" id="x_test" value="1"  />
```

now using Jquery if I want to select this input, for instance to hide it:

```
$( "#x_test" ).hide();
```

This does not work unless I remove the hashtags from the name of the element.
But I'm doing a select by ID I'm not sure why this is such an issue.

Is this a known issue & is there something I can do?

We are on jquery-1.3.2

Thanks

***UPDATE***

Thanks for all the hints, it helped me a bit and I did learn some things from them but in the end the problem was bad existing code from someone else interfering with what I was trying to do.

We have a wizard en in each step it copies the inputs from that page to a hidden dynamic form for this wizard.

But they were also copying the id-attribute etc so this didn't respect the rule of unique id's anymore. Because of this JQuery / JQuery UI and all my JavaScript were behaving realy weird ofcourse. I ended up rewriting this wizard-thing so my JQuery etc do work.

Comment: jQuery 1.3.2 is very old.

Comment: Your issue isn't reproducible: http://jsfiddle.net/qm0zecsd/ -- Seems to work as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To select by attribute:

```
$('[name="#x_test#"]').hide();
```

To select by id:

```
$('#x_test').hide();
```

or

```
$('[id="x_test"]').hide();
```

Check the below code (with jQuery 1.3.2).

The id selection applies a green colour, instead the name attribute selection applies a red colur:

```js
$('#test').css({'color':'green'});
$('[name="#test"]').css({'color':'red'});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">test id</div>
<div name="#test">name test</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, it did work like this and that brought me on the lead of the actual issue which was "non unique ID's" as described in my update of the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Use attribute equals selector:

```
$("[name='#x_test#']").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

if usage of # will not be working for your framework, try attaching the id name to class and use class selector in jQuery

i.e Have

```
<label width='auto' for='x_test' >Test:</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="#x_test#" id="x_test" class="x_test"  value="1"  />
```

and then use

```
$( ".x_test" ).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

this will works fine for me.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label width='auto' for='x_test' >Test:</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="#x_test#" id="x_test" value="1"  />
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () { 
    $( "#x_test" ).hide();    
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
$("input[name='#x_test#']").hide();
```